# Database Model - Tournaments for eSports

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, innodb

I'm quite new to Database Modelling and I'm struggling a bit with my **Tournament Module Structure.**

The **following** is what I managed to come up with **so far**:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igf4M.png)

**Overview**:

1. **(TABLE) Seasons** - All tournaments/leagues/ladders fall under it. Plain & simple.
2. **(TABLE) Tournaments:**

   - Related to the 'parent'->*seasons* via *season_id*
   - **Tournament Format** - allow **1vs1** or **team-based** participation.
   - **Tournament Type** - as the name hints: tournament, league, ladder
   - The rest in **Tournaments** is pretty self-explanatory so I'll skip ahead.

     1. **(SUB-TABLE)Tournament Entries** - **1 Table Row** per **Every Participating Player, AND Team** (If format is Team-based). It's moderated with column *is_team* (= 0, means Player Entry).
     2. **(SUB-TABLE)Tournament Matches** - connected to **Tournaments** via **entry_id->tournament_id** (Possible?). Columns *team A & B* are populated based on *entry_id->is_team* (When 0 assigns *entry_id->player_id* otherwise *entry_id->team_id*).
3. **(TABLE) Player Statistics** - **1 Table Row** per **Every Team PLAYED FOR during Tournament** => meanning, a Player can:

   1. Transfer teams in the **same** tournament.
   2. View **previous** recorded stats during the time he played for them.

I'm struggling with structuring current stage/phase of the tournament, play-offs, groups, single/double elimination, loser bracket and round-robin. In addition, how to track 'Best of' type of matches. How do I track that and create matches (new and based on previous results)?
Also, are my created relations & indexes correct and efficient?

NOTE: don't pay attention to the field types, it will be re-organized.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please ask a specific question about a specific design subset & explain about being stuck. Then we can talk precisely about aspects of & variants of that. Justify by referring to a specific textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. (Nb--A manual for a design tool, api or language to record designs is not a manual/tutorial on design.) Otherwise you are just asking us to rewrite one with a bespoke tutorial.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep. Make your post self-contained.  Please read & act on [mcve].